.Net 8 Nullable String Parameter set to "Microsoft.OData.ODataNullValue" instead of null
Recently migrated our project from .NET6 to .NET 8. During the process we also migrated our ODATA 7 from 8
Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData from "7.5.12" to "8.1.0"
I'm trying to keep the API signature and results the same, to avoid needing to adjust a number of consumers.
Model Configuration or Function Definition:
`FunctionConfiguration getInstances = builder.Function("GetDeploymentInstanceForPool")
.Returns<Component>();
getInstances.Parameter<string>("DeploymentInstanceType");
getInstances.Parameter<string>("PoolId");
getInstances.Parameter<string>("ParentInstanceId");`
Controller Action:
[HttpGet("odata/GetDeploymentInstanceForPool(DeploymentInstanceType={deploymentInstanceType},PoolId={poolId},ParentInstanceId={parentInstanceId})")] public async Task<IActionResult> GetDeploymentInstanceForPool(     [FromRoute] string deploymentInstanceType,     [FromRoute] string poolId,     [FromRoute] string parentInstanceId) {
.....
Prior to the upgrade odata/GetDeploymentInstanceForPool(DeploymentInstanceType='AXServiceFabricInstance',PoolId='{0}',ParentInstanceId=null)  would set ParentInstanceId to null
After the upgrade the API call is setting ParentInstanceId to "Microsoft.OData.ODataNullValue".
Can you please guilde here on how to resolve this issue as it fails my call taking "Microsoft.OData.ODataNullValue" instead of null value.
Tried
Option 1
getInstances.Parameter<string>("ParentInstanceId").Optional(); 
under Fucntion definition with no change
Option 2
getInstances.Parameter<string>("ParentInstanceId").Optional().HasDefaultValue(null); 
under Fucntion definition with no change
Option 3
getInstances.Parameter<string>("ParentInstanceId").Optional().HasDefaultValue(null).Nullable = true; 
under Fucntion definition with no change
